# Should app invoked by shortcut to network drive .EXE avoid JET related errors over wifi network?

Tags: ms-access, vb6, jet

I have a problem with a VB6 app using a Access-MDB database.

A customer has the `.MDB` and app `.EXE` located on a network drive over a wifi network.  On one of the workstations, when the app is invoked by a shortcut to the `.EXE` on the network drive there are no errors, but when the app is installed and run locally on the workstation (with the `.MDB` remaining on the network drive) there is an error.

Here is the relevant part of the code. The error message reported is "Unable to update at this time. Try again later."

```
Private Sub UpdateHistory()

Dim ecnt As Integer
Dim bInTrans As Boolean

On Error GoTo HistErr

bInTrans = False
ecnt = 0
Randomize
DBEngine.SetOption dbLockDelay, 90 + Rnd * 60
DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache
SWWorkspace.BeginTrans
If action = 1 Then
    historyfile.AddNew
    historyfile("customerid") = gblpkey
    historyfile("operatorid") = CurrentOperator
    historyfile("type") = gbltype
    historyfile("date") = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    If gbltype = 1 Or gbltype = 2 Or gbltype = 6 Then
      historyfile("rtype") = "Manual"
    End If
Else   
    historyfile.Edit
End If
saveDate = historyfile("date")
historyfile("memo") = ptext
historyfile.Update
SWWorkspace.CommitTrans dbForceOSFlush
bInTrans = False

Exit Sub

HistErr:

    ecnt = ecnt + 1
    If ecnt > 10 Then
        If bInTrans Then
          SWWorkspace.Rollback
          bInTrans = False
        End If
        Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
        MsgBox "Unable to update at this time. Try again later. "     
        Exit Sub
    End If

  sleep 1
  DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache
  Resume

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared when I placed the EXE on the network drive and put a shortcut to it on the other workstation.  I can only assume that invoking an EXE via a shortcut to a network location plays some part in preventing a wifi connection dropping out when accessing an MDB.

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch the real error. ATM the only error msg you told us is the custom error msg from the app "Unable to update at this time. Try again later." ....which is a catch all error msg after 10 error retries.

Comment: I don't know what the real error is.  I assume the error is due to the wifi connection dropping out.

Comment: Could be permissions...could be anything. You need the real error msg.

Comment: @oczecho: The error doesn't occur when the app is invoked via shortcut to the network drive .exe

Comment: Your code ignores the real error. Try getting the value of `Err.Number` and `Err.Description` after the `HistErr:` label.

Comment: @Deanna: It doesn't really matter what the error is because it will be some sort of JET or file access error due to the wifi network.

Comment: @CraigJohnston: No, no error messages matter at all, ever. *facepalm* More seriously, of course they matter, they tell you exactly why it went wrong, and very often, a solution. If you Continue to refuse to post useful information, you won't get much more help...</rant>

Comment: @Deanna: I won't have any opportunity to put in a new version of the code at the site for some time, so I need to be able to think about the problem as is.  The code works fine at other places so I have to assume it is related to the wifi and the shortcut.

Comment: @CraigJohnston Your logic is mind-boggling. *We need to know what the error actually is before we can hope to even guess* what the problem is.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I don't know what the error is exactly, because I haven't had a chance to put in new code that will expose the actual error number etc.  I need to be able to analyse this problem with the currently available information.

Comment: @CraigJohnston It is impossible to do so. You asked this question before you had access to all the information needed.

Comment: To eliminate WIFI use ethernet cable. I dont think its WIFI connectivity issue.

Comment: @ozczecho: I cannot impose this requirement on a customer. Like a lot of small businesses these days they like to use wifi.